# how to resolve org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback;

Tags: sql, spring, prepared-statement, hsqldb

I am using HSQLDB as my database. i want to get a primary key of latest inserted row. for that i have return a query in my java class as below:

```
final String query = "INSERT INTO polling_log (start_date,status,action) VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,?,?); CALL IDENTITY();";
    GeneratedKeyHolder generatedKeyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    int update = adapterJdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
        @Override
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(
                Connection connection) throws SQLException {

            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection
                    .prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, pollingLogVO.getStatus());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, pollingLogVO.getAction());
            System.out.println(preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys().getFetchSize());
            return preparedStatement;
        }
    }, generatedKeyHolder);

    System.out.println("###################### "+ update);

    Number logId = generatedKeyHolder.getKey();
    pollingLogId = logId.intValue();
```

and to store the query i have used GeneratedKeyHolder. but while runing this i get an exception:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: unexpected token: IDENTITY
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:98)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:602)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:817)
    at com.platysgroup.lmex.adapter.moodle.dao.LogDao.insertPollingLog(LogDao.java:36)
    at com.platysgroup.lmex.adapter.MoodlePostingTask.insertPollingLog(MoodlePostingTask.java:134)
    at com.platysgroup.lmex.adapter.MoodlePostingTask.run(MoodlePostingTask.java:55)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: unexpected token: IDENTITY
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:248)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:302)
    at com.platysgroup.lmex.adapter.moodle.dao.LogDao$1.createPreparedStatement(LogDao.java:41)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:580)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: IDENTITY
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: @javanna: I can't see your answer..

Comment: @jabal - that's because he/she deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line (wrapped for clarity):

> `final String query = "INSERT INTO polling_log (start_date,status,action) VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,?,?); CALL IDENTITY();";`

The issue is that `IDENTITY` is a reserved word in SQL; it's got a meaning pre-defined already and so can't be used like that in a `CALL` statement. (I don't know what it is actually used for; the full definition of SQL is huge and has a very large number of reserved words.) The immediate work around would be to enclose the problem word in double quotes (which would need to be backslash-quoted because of being in a Java string):

> `final String query = "INSERT INTO polling_log (start_date,status,action) VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,?,?); CALL \"IDENTITY\"();";`

However, if you're just calling that to get the inserted row, ***STOP!*** Just let Spring do the work for you, assuming you have JDBC 3.0 or later (i.e., Java 5 or later).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot put more than one statements into one string to be executed. Execute two separate operations instead of this.

Answer (score 0):

The following link has what you need:

http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/jdbc/spring-jdbc-insert-auto-generated-key